# Suppress Invalid write of size valgrind's Memcheck error

Tags: memory-leaks, valgrind

I am trying to profile my application for checking possible memory leaks using Valgrind's memcheck tool. As my application has many dependent 3rd party libraries, which are reporting 'Invalid write of size' memory error. How do I suppress this error? I have tried make options in the suppression file such as Cond, Value4, Addr4. But nothing has suppressed this warning. I have also provided the option --undef-value-errors=no

Answer (score 1):

Use
    --gen-suppressions=all
and edit the resulting generated suppressions (e.g. to make them more general
and give a name to them)